# Hibernate Annotation Field Definition

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am currently exploring Hibernate annotation and I am finding it better than having a lot of configuration XML files.

However, I cannot find the documentation for the each annotation.  For example, I would like to check out the list of attributes of an @table annotation other than name.

I checked out the doc files and API from the downloaded hibernate annotation but can't find any complete reference.  Where can I see or download it?

I am new to annotations as we are working solely on Java 1.4 before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `javax.persistence` classes are part of the JavaEE 5 API.  See the [javadoc here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html).

The Hibernate Annotations docs only document the Hibernate proprietary extensions to the base JavaEE API.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing for this is to just attach the source code in your favorite IDE. This is included with the Hibernate archived you might have downloaded.

If you are using Hibernate as part of a Java EE application server (via JPA), check their website first. They may offer a complete source attachment for your AS or at least give you information about the exact versions being used.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide" - first link shoul be fine for you https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

or maybe better:

google "Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide pdf" - first link should be https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf